# Are Bounty Reasons disparaging people as "poor" something we want to condone?

Tags: discussion, bounty

There's currently a question bountied with the reason given as:

> i am very rich...giving away my points...to poor...

That wording, intent aside, seems like a very unkind way to oversee things.

Are we ok with this?

Answer (score 7):

I'm just one person and therefore can't determine whether "we" are OK with it. *I personally* am not much bothered by it; I don't think calling someone "poor" is insulting them, especially when (as here) it seems obviously intended mostly as a joke.

It certainly doesn't seem like it needs any kind of punishment.

However, I *do* agree that it's not a great thing to be saying, since (as we see here) some people *will* read it as disparaging. So, for the record: I hereby declare that it is better *not* to describe people with less PSE rep as "poor", or using any other terms that you might feel uncomfortable about using to describe someone who in the real world had (say) less money, or a lower measured IQ, or a lower-ranked job in a corporate hierarchy.

Comment: It's especially strange in this particular case, because the "poor" users all (except for one) have at _least_ ~5 times, and at _most_ ~60 times, as much reputation as the bounty-giving user!